# How to return a function where the input tuple contains an empty set?

Tags: python, list, function, set, tuples

```
CATALOGUE = {("table", 9999, 20), ("chair", 2999, 5), ("lamp", 1999, 10)}      

def add_item_to_order(name, quantity, order):
    number=0
    lookup=[]
    new={}
    catlist=list(CATALOGUE)
    
    for item in name, quantity, order:
        for item in order:
            lookup=list(order)
            for cat in catlist:
                if name==lookup[0][0]:
                    newnumber=number+quantity+lookup[0][1]
                    new={(lookup[0][0],newnumber,lookup[0][2],lookup[0][3])}
                elif name in cat and len(lookup)!=0: 
                    new={(lookup[0][0],lookup[0][1],lookup[0][2],lookup[0][3]),(cat[0],quantity,cat[1],cat[2])}
                elif name in cat and len(lookup)==0:
                    new={(cat[0],quantity,cat[1],cat[2])}
                return new
            else:
                raise KeyError
                    
     
add_item_to_order("table", 1, set())
```

I have an assignment where a tuple with name, quantity and order(a set) is input into a function. Based on whether the order matches the name,  the function return a new set e.g. {("table"(name),1 (quantity), 9999(price in pence), 20 (weight)}, where the quantity is updated.
If  the name does not match the order and if the name matches the catalogue, then this generates a set of two tuples e.g.{('chair', 1, 2999, 5), ('table', 1, 9999, 20)}. If the set in order for the input is empty then a set of one tuple from the CATALOGUE which matches the name in the input is returned e.g. for above code should return {("table", 1, 9999, 20}. The above code is able to work for the 1st two conditions, however returns a Nonetype if there is an empty set for order in the input as shown in the input. I was wondering how I could solve this?

Comment: `new={}` creates an empty dictionary, not an empty set. Use `new=set()` to create an empty set.

Comment: You're always returning from the function on the first iteration of the `for` loop. That's probably not what you want.

Comment: I don't understand the second case. Why is `chair` in the result when you're just adding `table`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be adding items to `new` each time through the loop, not replacing the whole variable.

`return new` should be at the end of the function, not inside the loop.

And `new` should be initialized as a set, not a dictionary.

`for item in name, quantity, order:` makes no sense at all. You can use `for item in order:` or `for name, quantity, price, weight in order:`. You also don't need nested loops, just one loop over `order`.

I don't understand why you're converting `order` to a list and then just testing `lookup[0]`. You should be using `item` in the loop, not `order`.

You don't need to convert `CATALOGUE` to a list to iterate over it.

```
def add_item_to_order(name, quantity, order):
    new = set()
    name_matched = False
    for oname, oquantity, oprice, oweight in order:
        if oname == name:
            name_matched = True
            new.add((name, oquantity + quantity, oprice, oweight))
        else:
            new.add((name, oquantity, oprice))
            
    if not name_matched:
        for cname, cprice, cweight in CATALOGUE:
            if cname == name:
                new.add((name, quantity, cprice, cweight))
                break
        else:
            raise KeyError(f"{name} not found in CATALOGUE")
    
    return new
```

Comment: Thank you for your helpful reply. Apologies for the poor code as I'm relatively new at this. I'm afraid your code doesn't work for when the name is not name_matched. It throws a KeyError error with name not found in CATALOGUE, even if name is in CATALOGUE.

Comment: I forgot the `break` statement. Now it should work.